# Sub-select in a variable in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I have the following OrientDB SQL query:

```
select expand($all) let
$a = (select groups, inV().firstName from (
    select expand(outE()) from (select from user where uuid = 'abc')
)),
$b = (select groups, outV().firstName from (
    select expand(inE()) from (select from user where uuid = 'abc')
)),
$all = unionall($a, $b)
```

It's irrelevant what the query tries to accomplish. Anyway, it works in this form. But, as you can notice, there is **duplication** of `select from user where uuid = 'abc'`. How can I extract that part into a variable and reuse it multiple times?

---

I already tried:

```
select expand($all) let
$x = (select from user where uuid = 'abc'),
$a = (select groups, inV().firstName from (
    select expand(outE()) from $x
)),
$b = (select groups, outV().firstName from (
    select expand(inE()) from $x
)),
$all = unionall($a, $b)
```

and

```
select expand($all) let
$x = (select from user where uuid = 'abc'),
$a = (select groups, inV().firstName from (
    select expand($x.outE())
)),
$b = (select groups, outV().firstName from (
    select expand($x.inE())
)),
$all = unionall($a, $b)
```

and

```
select expand($all) let
$x = first((select from user where uuid = 'abc')),
$a = (select groups, inV().firstName from (
    select expand($x.outE())
)),
$b = (select groups, outV().firstName from (
    select expand($x.inE())
)),
$all = unionall($a, $b)
```

but, to no avail. All the queries are parsed successfully, but return empty result. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The query that you have shown only 'combines' multiple queries into single query and gives the result.

The variables that you declare hold the result of that particular query which can be used in SQL functions like `UNIONALL()`. You cannot use that in other queries.

I have not found anything of the this type in the documentation. Perhaps a newer version will support it!